# How to copy entire image from SD card to external hard drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, raspberrypi, sd-card

I recently bought RPI4 with 64GB SD card my operating system is working fine from SD card but I would like to clone whole image from my SD card to my external hard drive so I can remove my SD card and my machine should reboot from external HDD. I tried Clonzilla Device-Device option but the problem I face Clonzilla only recognize my external hard drive as sources and unable to find my boo table SD card
Thane I have read some tutorials about Multi-system to use with clonezilla, I downloaded Multi-system on  my system extract it to my desktop and when I extract to install this software in terminal it's end up with error and it is unable to install
can someone please recommend how can I achieve my goal to copy existing Ubuntu OS to external hard drive and boot my OS from hard disk

Comment: Would you mind editing your post to increase readability? Please add some punctuation marks to mark the end of one sentence and the beginning of the next, and correct some spelling errors.

Answer (score 2):

### Using dd to Clone File System from One Drive to Another

- Create Live Ubuntu USB and Boot it
- Plug in Target drive, (must be at least as large as Source drive).
- Open Gnome-Disks to confirm drive designations, sda, sdb, etc.
- In Terminal run `sudo dd if=/dev/sdx of=/dev/sdy`

  Where `sdx` is the Source drive and `sdy` is the Target drive. **Double check that the Target device designation is correct, one typo can overwrite your OS.**

  Some people prefer to add a block size, such as `bs=256k`, but I do not bother.

  **The process may take a long time.**

  Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/805-7228/bkupsavefiles-60904/index.html

Comment: You may also want to include a warning that it is best to double check that the output device is correct...

Comment: @vanadium: hopefully Item 3, confirming drive designations, should do that. Do you think I should reword that item?

Comment: The warning could a bit stronger ;)

Comment: There, that looks strong to me..

Comment: For sure it is :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've done this, but it was a while ago, cloning from the SD card to an M.2 SATA drive in a USB enclosure. Pretty sure I was using an early version of Twister OS, which is based on Raspbian. An application called "SD Card Copier" has been included in Raspbian and Twister OS for a while.

If it was on your system it would be under "Accessories" in the application menu.

I have a Pi with the latest Twister OS Lite and had to install the "SD Card Copier" utility with "sudo apt install piclone". Don't know if you can do that if you're running Ubuntu on the Pi. Probably not.

So you'd most likely have to try another utility like this:

https://github.com/billw2/rpi-clone

Just follow the instructions on the page.