# How to recover data from an old HDD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, hardware, external-hdd

I recently replaced my HDD(Ubuntu 20) with an SSD. I want to copy the data that was on the old HDD to the new SSD. I've put the old HDD in an enclosure but my pc can't even detect the old HDD. How do I get my pc to detect it and copy the data stored in it?

Comment: How long ago did you stop using the HDD? Is it properly mounted in the USB enclosure? Does the enclosure require 5V of power, or 3.3? (You may need to plug it into a powered USB hub rather than directly into the computer)

Comment: Is the drive visible from an Ubuntu Live USB? If so you can clone it using dd: https://askubuntu.com/a/1339454/43926

Comment: If you plug the old drive into the motherboard using SATA cables you will get much better performance than by using USB and you will avoid issues with the USB enclosures.

Comment: Unplug the drive, in a terminal type `tail -f /var/log/syslog` and replug the drive. What do you see?

Comment: Does enclosure have separate power, not just USB. I used an adapter for an old SSD that was only USB powered. It worked great for SSD. But when I tried to use it with old HDD, not enough power, drive would not spin up.

Answer (score 0):

If your PC doesn't detect the old HDD then you have a hardware problem.
Either the enclosure or the HDD is defective or you haven't plugged it in properly.

Go through the usual exclusion process: check all cables, try a different (known working) HDD, try a different enclosure, try connecting the HDD directly to the mainboard.